# extjs form post rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, extjs

i am newbie to Ext JS...I want to post Ext JS form data to server...
How am i supposed to proceed? i am using Ext JS with rails...
I have followed link : [Ext JS With rails](http://www.extjswithrails.com/2009/06/restful-store-example-with-rails_04.html) but no luck..

Comment: thanx but i dont want to use Netzke & i found solution.. ` var sbtn=Ext.getCmp('submitbtn');
        sbtn.on('click',function(){
            var frm=Ext.getCmp('FormPanel');
        frm.el.unmask();
        frm.getForm().submit(
            url = '/customers/new');
        })  `            In the rails controller : `def create
    @customer = Customer.new(params[:custdata])
   if @customer.save
      
      format.json {render :json => @customer, :success => true, :message => "Created new User #{@customer.id}", :custdata => @customer}
       end  `

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using Netzke, e.g.: http://blog.writelesscode.com/blog/2010/06/14/extjs-rails-crud-application-in-7-minutes/

Comment: thanx but i dont want to use Netzke & i found solution.. ` var sbtn=Ext.getCmp('submitbtn');
        sbtn.on('click',function(){
            var frm=Ext.getCmp('FormPanel');
        frm.el.unmask();
        frm.getForm().submit(
            url = '/customers/new');
        })  `

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided discuss about Restful Ext JS store operations. Have a look at this [simple example from the same site](http://www.extjswithrails.com/2008/03/sending-forms-old-way-with-ext-js.html).

You can also make use of Netzke as mentioned by Nomad. But, I am not sure of the framework's compatibility with new version of Ext Js. If you plan to use Ext Js I would suggest you start working with Ext JS 4 straight away.